# Why won't the truffle move in

Tags: terraria

Ok. So I defeated the wall of flesh. I created this a mushroom biome and the truffle won't move in. I have a mushroom door, mushroom work bench, a table, torches, and it's made out of mushroom grass. There are also mushroom monsters that I see in the underground mushroom biome and I see the giant mushrooms in the background. I know there is not a crimson or a corrupt biome nearby by because I cleansed them. My house is also the right heigth. The truffle keeps saying he wants to move in. Please help me figure out why the truffle won't move in.

Comment: A picture of the house and surrounding area may help. Also - please tag your questions appropriately - this is Terraria *not* Minecraft.

Comment: Truffle only moves in to *surface* mushroom biomes. From the wording in your question, it sounds like you created the biome underground.